# Low frame rate with Greensock animation

Tags: animation, frame-rate, gsap

I've built an animation with greensock and I checked the frame rates with Chrome Devtools in incognito. Unforunately I have massive frame drops:
[Here are the FPS numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkcLB.jpg)

---

[Here is the animation](https://szsoma.github.io/sandbox/omlab.html)

Can I optimize this animation somehow?

Comment: Basically the issue seems to be the popup animation. Have you tried using an image and sprites for the text animation?. Unfortunately SVG elements can't be hardware accelerated so perhaps you should consider changing that.

Comment: Looks like you're getting quite a few answers here: https://greensock.com/forums/topic/16788-repaint-in-animation/. The animation played smoothly for me. It does look like you're loading a lot of stuff into that page that isn't used and might be eating resources. Like Rodrigo said, SVG can't be GPU-accelerated.